# Session Expired due to inactivity in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I've got session expired due to inactivity error on jmeter script execution.
Could anyone please tell me what will be causing the problem.

Comment: Are you using a cookie manager?

Comment: yes i am using cookie manager and cache manger

Answer (score 0):

In case of Java or .NET web application it may be cause by incorrect [VIEWSTATE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/viewstate/info) value - dynamic mandatory parameter reflecting current state of things on the webpage or something like this.

If it is the case you need to [correlate](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html) the variable. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for detailed explanation on the domain.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,I have correlated all the values,it is a checkout flow.Everything is going fine but only REST call is throwing an error during payment

Comment: does anyone know any website where i can find paid expert to answer my jmeter question

Comment: Then something is wrong with your REST call, a parameter is missing or incorrect. In regards to site you can try http://www.experts-exchange.com/ but I doubt that it will help